# When should I close the database connection in this simple web app?

Tags: go

I’m writing a simple Go web application that uses PostgreSQL. My `main` function looks like

```
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Couldn't connect to the database: %v", err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/whatever", whateverHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", nil)
}
```

It seems like I should be calling `Close()` on the database connection at some point, but when? This application serves forever (i.e. until I kill it with `^C`). If I put code after the `ListenAndServe` call it doesn’t get run, because my `^C` has killed the entire application. Should my application be structured differently?

Comment: As Elwinar said, in this case it doesn't matter, but usually you put `defer foo.Close()` right after whatever resource you open. Otherwise, you might forget to call `Close` later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, I tend to say you don't even need to bother: the connection will be closed when the program end, so you won't leak anything.

If you really need to close things properly, the simpler choice is to use a [graceful](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/graceful) server, and `defer` the resources closing.

Or, if your use case is more complicated, do it by hand by catching [signals](https://godoc.org/os/signal) and gracefully shutting down your own way (using a closing channel for example).

Comment: Great. I’m new to Go and it wasn’t clear to me that the connection would be closed even if the application was killed.

Comment: Note that in the case of database connections, it's not super critical to you `db.Close` the entire pool. Else catching a signal (SIGTERM) and running it before actually calling `os.Exit` is probably the "safest" way to go. Don't get too distracted by that if you're just starting out.

Answer (score 5):

It is important to understand that `sql.Open()` does not open a connection to the database... http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open

> Open may just validate its arguments without creating a connection to the database. To verify that the data source name is valid, call Ping.

Also it is important to understand that the driver handles the maintance of connections. So you will likely want to keep it open for the lifetime of your app.

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.